# Get eventID of a raised event in .net?

Tags: vb.net, events

I raised a event in .net and now I want to get the eventID of it.
But how? Couldn't apply any solution from the internet.

Comment: What EventID? An event doesn't "by default" have an EventID; *if* there's any it's probably in the [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) (derived) object passed into the event; usually `e`. So try `e.EventId` or something. Without code and more information we can't tell. Read up on [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).

Comment: Please, show us some code and give us more information. We need to see what you mean by `eventID`, how you raise your events and where you need to get that `eventID`. The way you asked the question does give us enough info to help you

Comment: I declare my event like `Event controlEvent()`, it's triggered by a button click `    `Public Sub RaiseControlEvent() 
RaiseEvent controlEvent()
 End Sub`

I was told that every event I create in .net is given a ID in my user control. So I thought I could add a handler function and print out this ID for the beginning.

Comment: We just found out that getting the eventID in .net is probably not possible. We used OLEview which showed our registered control and the registered event in it. There we found the "ID" 0x0000001